# R h2o.deeplearning obtaining probabilities with classification mode

Tags: r, regression, classification, h2o

I am using h2o.deeplearning to train a neural network on a classification task.

**What I have**

Y ~ x1 + x2... where all x variables are continuous and Y is binary.

**What I want**

To be able to train a deeplearning object to predict the probability of a given row of being true or false. That is, a predicted(Y) restricted to between 0 and 1.

**What I've tried**
When Y is inputted as a numeric (i.e. 0 or 1), h2o deeplearning automatically treats it as a regression problem. This is fine, except the final layer of the NN is linear, not tanh, and the predicted values can be greater than 1 or less than 0. I've not been able to find a way to get the final layer to be a tanh.

When Y is inputted as categorical (i.e. TRUE or FALSE), h2o deeplearning automatically treats it as a classification problem. Instead of giving me the desired probability of Y being 1 or 0, it gives me its best guess of what Y is.

Is there a way around this? A trick, tweak or an overlooked parameter? I have noticed in the h2o.deeplearning documentation a 'distribution' parameter, but no further information on what that's for. My best guess is that it is some kind of link function in the same vein as GLM, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Well, you haven't offered any code. You haven't offered any data. And you haven't offered any links to sites whose documentation you have already researched, so we have no idea how much effort you put into this. I wonder if this might be closer to the topics handled at the beta data science section of stackexchange? (And don't blame me, they aren't my votes, so these are just guesses as to motivations.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you treat the problem as a binary classification problem then you not only get the “prediction” of 0 or 1, but also the p0 and p1 probabilities that add up to 1.  These are the probabilies that the predicted value is the negative and positive class, respectively.

Then just use p1 directly.